# GRUB repair issue - duplicate Ubuntu and no Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I tried to repaid grub via Boot-Repaid and these are the results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7894957/

Currently I have two Ubuntus listed (but they boot into the same system) and the Windows disappeared.

Could someone please help me? I'm not experienced with Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: open a terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l`. Add this information to your question.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` won't add any useful information to what's already in Boot Repair's output.

Answer (score 1):

One of your two `ubuntu` entries boots Ubuntu via Shim (which then launches GRUB), which works with Secure Boot on or off. The other boots it via GRUB, but without Shim; this works only if Secure Boot is disabled.

You shouldn't be seeing the firmware's boot menu with the two `ubuntu` entries unless you hit a function key or Esc early in the boot process. (Precisely how you bring up this menu varies from one computer to another.) Thus, I recommend you leave it alone. You could remove the `Boot0000` entry (which boots without Shim) or the `Boot0001` entry (which boots via Shim), but doing so runs a (small) risk of user error or running into some new or obscure EFI bug that will end up creating new problems. Since the double-`ubuntu` issue is both a trivial cosmetic problem and unlikely to be something you see very often, IMO it's better to ignore it than to run even a small risk of creating a much bigger problem. Furthermore, the entry you remove might be added back the next time a GRUB update rolls around.

If you insist on removing one entry, do so with `efibootmgr`:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
```

This example removes the `Boot0000` entry; change `0000` as appropriate to remove any other entry.

Comment: Thanks! But what about the Windows option? It completely disappeared, and update-grub is not locating it. The partition with Windows is still there.

Comment: The options shown by `efibootmgr`, and by the firmware when you hit a function key (or whatever) early in the boot process, are *EFI boot manager* boot options. GRUB maintains an *entirely separate* set of boot options. Using `update-grub` updates the GRUB options, but doesn't touch the EFI booot manager's options. To edit the EFI boot manager's options, you use `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu, `bcfg` in an EFI shell, `bcdedit` in Windows, or the EFI setup utility's user interface.